# TypeScript Visual Studio Language Extension Source Code

Tags: typescript

Does anyone know where the source code for the VS source code extension for TypeScript can be found?

I wanted to have a snoop to see if I could plugin some primitive XML documentation features, but I don't appear to be able to find the source for the plugin.

I imagine it's possible to extend the language extension with a VS extension anyway, but I thought a look would help this process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TypeScript project is open source under the Apache 2.0 license - but the plugins for the various IDE's are not necessarily open source.

The TypeScript for Visual Studio extension is [downloadable from the Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790), rather than Codeplex, which suggests it isn't open source at this time.

Comment: There is a license agreement in the visx file. It's called TypeScript_License.rtf and licenses you to use, but not to alter the software. It is not open source.